# Calculus of variation for maps between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, calculus-of-variations

I am used to seeing examples in calculus of variations with functionals acting on curves in manifolds, i.e. $$\mathcal{L}(\gamma) = \int_0^1 L(t, \gamma(t), \dot{\gamma}(t) ) dt$$ for $\gamma : [0,1] \to N$ a smooth curve in a smooth manifold $N$, and $L: \mathbb{R} \times N \times TN \to \mathbb{R}$ (I'm not fully sure of the domain of $L$ in this case, actually). $L$ is often said to be time dependent.

I am interested in the natural generalization where the time dependency is changed to that of another manifold $M$, i.e. for $f : M \to N$, we have something that may look like $$ \mathcal{L}(f) = \int_M L (p, f(p), df_p) dVol. $$ (Again I am unsure of the domain of $L$ in this case, or if $df_p$ even appears in the expression.)

Is this the correct formulation for this generalization? If so, how would one define the functional derivative of $\mathcal{L}$, if it even exists, in order to, say, work with the Euler-Lagrange equations? I'm having trouble finding anything clear about the subject in the online literature.

The specific example I am looking at is of the form $$\mathcal{L}(f) = \int_M X(h \circ f) dVol, $$ where $X$ is a vector field over $M$ and $h$ is a smooth real function over $N$. Perhaps using this example to illustrate my above questions would be more helpful.

Comment: Do the same as you did for a curve. Extend $f$ to be a parameterized family of masp $f_t: M \rightarrow N$ and differentiate $\mathcal{L}(f)$ with respect to  $t$.

Comment: @Deane When you say parametrized, do you mean by $\mathbb{R}$ in the $t$ component? In that case, taking the derivative with respect to $t$ would use the chain rule to differentiate $f$ inside, right? (Assuming we can differentiate under the integral.)

Comment: The domain of $L$ will be the jet bundle $J^1(M, N).$ It might help to check out a mathematical introduction to classical field theory - your problem is exactly the field theory with spacetime $M$ and field bundle $M \times N \to M.$

Comment: Yes. Differentiate under the integral. No reason to worry about whether you can or not. It’s just a formal calculation to figure out vagaries the Euler-Lagrange equations are.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks for the pointer. I can't seem to find a good introductory set of notes on this topic, though. Could you recommend one?